# Golang: Why selector to pointers is illegal after comparison?

Tags: pointers, go, methods, types

I'm reading the spec about selectors: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors

[image]

Why `q.M0()` is invalid. While `p.M0()` is valid and `q=p`. Very strange for me.

The relevant source code:

```
type T0 struct {
    x int
}

func (*T0) M0()

type T1 struct {
    y int
}

func (T1) M1()

type T2 struct {
    z int
    T1
    *T0
}

func (*T2) M2()

type Q *T2

var t T2     // with t.T0 != nil
var p *T2    // with p != nil and (*p).T0 != nil
var q Q = p

p.M0()       // ((*p).T0).M0()      M0 expects *T0 receiver
q.M0()       // (*q).M0 is valid but not a field selector
```

Comment: I know that the documentation explains it. But please do not downvote. If I ask, it is mean that I tried to understand, and did not success.  I know 2 things: *1.* People here like to downvote `golang` questions. *2.* People here have stronger ability to explain complicated things in Markdown language.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why `q.M0()` is invalid. While `p.M0()` is valid and `q=p`. Very strange for me.

`q` is initialized like `var q Q = p`, but it does not mean they are equal. The [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) is valid because it does not violate the [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) rules, but type of `q` is different than type of `p`.

Type of `q` is `Q` (where `type Q *T2`), and type of `p` is `*T2`.

In Go, methods belong to a specific type. When you do this:

```
type Q *T2
```

It creates a new type named `Q` (`*T2` being its underlying type). The new type will have 0 methods, it does not "inherit" any methods from `*T2`, hence `q.M0()` will be a compile-time error:

> q.M0 undefined (type Q has no field or method M0)

**Note:**

You may still think it's strange because `M0()` is declared like this:

```
func (*T0) M0()
```

It has `*T0` receiver so it belongs to the type `*T0`, yet type of `p` is `*T2`, so `*T2` should not have this `M0()` method and therefore `p.M0()` should also be invalid. But `T2` is a struct which [embeds](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types) `*T0`, and so methods of `*T0` are *promoted*, and they will be in the [method set](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) of `T2`.

Also see this related question: [Golang: Why selector to pointers is illegal after comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803654/golang-why-selector-to-pointers-is-illegal-after-comparison/40804236#40804236)

Comment: Thanks. Really helpful